# Blocking aggressive coin miner in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-worker

Thing is, how to inject code into foreign iframe which spawns a lot of workers and starts mining coins with all my CPU?

My basic idea was something like

```
for (var iframe of document.querySelectorAll('iframe')) {
    console.log("Removing Worker from ", iframe);
    iframe.window.eval("window.Worker = undefined;");   
}
```

Well, it does not work. Looks like iframes which are not from same origin are protected from WRITE access from parent frame.

URL blocking is not a way to go, page will detect it.

What to do now ?

Comment: Don't use the page -> everybody does so -> they loose customers -> they loose money -> they will change their way of earning ( nonintrusive ads maybe ) -> you can use them again ( i   capitalism )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject code into an iframe for security reasons. If you could, websites could post to stackoverflow without your permission by loading the page to post a question and selecting the submit button and using `.click()`. The only way to stop an iframe from loading a bitcoin miner is to not load the iframe.

Comment: I see. Actually, thats kinda bad, so only option is to not use a site afterall ...